# Windows Phone 8 - get to-do items

Tags: search, windows-phone-8, calendar

Is there any way how I can get "to-do" items from calendar? Something similar to searchasync on Appointments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Windows Phone 8 forum on MSDN. The api does not support getting to-do items.